# Why int[] aa={'12','2'}; is invalid and int[] aa={'1','2'}; is valid? error showing is Invalid character constant

Tags: java, arrays

Why int[] aa={'12','2'}; is invalid and int[] aa={'1','2'}; is valid?

error showing is Invalid character constant.

Comment: `'12'` is not a valid char literal. A char cannot contain two characters.

Comment: 12 is not a valid char.

Comment: '12' -> 1 is a character, 2 is a second character. it says it in the name: character. a char can be transformed to an int, but it must be a valid char

Comment: Because a `char` variable represents a single character. You decided it was a `char` when you used single quotes. Double quotes for a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

'1' and '2' are `char`s, which can be promoted to `int`, so they can be assigned to an `int` array. Note that the numeric values of '1' and '2' is not equal to the numbers 1 and 2. They are actually 49 and 50.

i.e.

```
int[] aa={'1','2'};
```

will result in the same array as:

```
int[] aa={49,50};
```

'12' is not a valid constant in Java.

If you want a `String`, it should be "12" (but in that case, you can't assign it to an `int` array). If you want an `int`, it should be 12 (i.e. without any quotes).

Answer (score 1):

Because the single quotes indicate 'single character value', and '12' is not a single character, but 2 characters in one go. Note that int a = '1' is valid, and doesn't do what you think it does. Run this code:

```
int a = '1';
System.out.println(a); // This prints... 49????
```

Yes, it prints 49. '1' is a character. It will silently upcast to an integer here, at which point, you're looking at its UTF codepoint (49). If you want an int array containing the value 12 and 2, it's just: `int[] aa = {12, 2};` - forget the quotes.